# Is there any function to sort an array in reverse order?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Is there any php function built in to make it easy to take a database of information and reverse the order in which it echo's while fetching it from a PHP script?

For instance a comment system, it would make it a lot easier if there was a function to reverse the order of the echo's to make the newest comment on the top.

Comment: How about changing the SQL query to something like ORDER BY date DESC

Answer (score 3):

yes...instead of echoing it out as you fetch row, you can first put the rows in an array and use `rsort` or `arsort` and then loop through and echo..or..you can do it in the mysql query (ideal) by adding `...order by columnname desc` to your query

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php

If you're returning an array from the database, this will do what you're looking for

Comment: or do as @Crayon Violent suggested and just change the db query

Comment: I agree, that's definitely a better way to go. But I answered the question that was asked, as opposed to providing a better solution. :) that way it might help someone else if they end up here via google or something

Answer (score 0):

The other option is simply to reverse the loop:

```
$count = count($aArray_Name);

for ( $i = $count; $i > 0; $i-- ) {
    echo $aArray_Name[$i];
}
```

May or may not work depending on your situation. Would most definitely be better to just modify the query as mentioned by others.

Comment: this probably won't work for his situation.  He probably has code that performs the query and then a while($r = mysql_fetch_...) loop